# How to Get the transaction details once the payment via paypal completed

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using  parallel adaptive payment. i got the php coding from following link of paypal developer` website.

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/adaptive/main.php

Now the transaction of amount takes place successfully. But i want to store the transactions details such as

1.transaction id,2. Amount 3.Status etc. After the returns from paypal to my website
Presently i did this with paypal sand box account

Answer (score 0):

You could use IPN to get information back to your website that pertains to the transaction.  You can find more on [IPN on PayPal Developer's Site.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Comment: i want to get it in return URL.. how can i get it, it does not return transaction details in url. For that what are the changes i need to do.?

Comment: This will not work this way.  You would have to use IPN to get the data back to your site.

Comment: How i can create ipn with my website, could u provide me sample code for that?

Comment: See the example script I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295552/is-it-possible-to-pass-the-amount-back-to-my-site/16300849#16300849

Comment: Now, I got success mail, but the following  Values are empty $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

Comment: Adaptive Payment IPN's get sent back a little bit differently than the classic IPN's.  They look similar to the following post.  Make sure that you are reading the values correctly.   transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn=...&transaction[0].receiver=paypal_1298736_biz@paypal.com&transaction[0].is_primary_receiver=false&transaction[0].id=...&transaction[0].status=Completed&transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn=Completed&transaction[0].amount=CAD+10.00

Comment: Is there a way to get the details by a POST request?